# How rotate source vector to target (to nearest vector) by using only 2 Euler angles

Tags: matrix, vector, geometry, coordinates, robotics

I need to rotate source 3D vector to target vector by rotation around only two axes YZ.

I have mechanism with 2 motors rotating around Y and then around Z. I have random source vector attached to this mechanism.

I think that source vector can't be rotated to random target 3D vector by using only 2 angles and I need to rotate it to the nearest to target vector.

I need to align only orientation, not coordinates.

What is the best way to do it with rotation matrices, quaternions, etc?

I can calculate shortestArcQuat from source vector to target. Then multiply target vector by inverse of this quat. And then get YZ angles from rotation matrix with the result of prev operation as Z vector but I think it's wrong.

Solution should be analytic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clarity in the notation let me define the unit vectors

```
E1 = (1,0,0)
E2 = (0,1,0)
E3 = (0,0,1)
```

Given a rotation matrix R the goal is deconpose it in two rotation matrices rotating an angle "a" around axis E2 and an angle "b" around axis E3:

```
R = exp(a E2) exp(b E3)
```

Multiplying both sides by E3

```
R E3 = exp(a E2) exp(b E3) E3
```

We get:

```
W = exp(a E2) E3
```

Where W is the vector E3 rotated by R: W = R E3

```
a = atan2( W • E1, W • E3)
```

Where (•) is the dot product.

Now taking the transpose of R we get:

```
R^T = exp(b E3)^T exp(a E2)^T
```

Multiplying both sides by E2:

```
R^T E2 = exp(b E3)^T exp(a E2)^T E2

R^T E2 = exp(-b E3) exp(-a E2) E2

S = exp(-b E3) E2
```

Where S is the vector E2 rotated by R^T: S = R^T E2

```
b = - atan2( S • E1, S • E2)
```

I have just derived those equations so this is untested and there might be some mistake. Take it as is.